# Audio player - Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following lines of code, but I keep getting a console error saying `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function` and I wasn't quite able to grasp the reason for this. Can someone kindly explain to me why I keep getting this error and possibly contribute to a better solution?

HTML

```
<audio id="audio-player" controls="" autoplay="">
    <source id="audio-source" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

JS

```
var playOnPageLoad = document.getElementbyId("audio-player");
playOnPageLoad.play();
```

Comment: You need to use `getElementById()` instead of `getElementbyId()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var playOnPageLoad = document.getElementById("audio-player");
playOnPageLoad.play();
```

```html
<audio id="audio-player" controls="" autoplay="">
    <source id="audio-source" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```